# Change pickletype on SqlAlchemyJobStore for APScheduler

Tags: pickle, apscheduler

Is there a way to change the pickletype from cPickle to dill or something else on the SQLAlchemyJobStore columns?

Answer (score 0):

Not unless you subclass the job store (and break compatibility in the process).